# SQL : How to get columns values aggregated and populate as new columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a huge SQL which result similar to Table1. Now I need to get the result set as Table2. This is from SQL Server but we dont have DB access as typical ways, Instead we have a internal tool where we can submit 'select' SQL statement and it'll dump excel file with the dataset. How can I get the result as table2 format?

Note: Due to the nature of the tool, we can use only SQL commands, cannot create StoredProcedure, View and etc.

Can we do something like this?

```
SELECT 'Columns' From (Original SQL command) WHERE xxx GROUPBY YYY
```

Table1

```
IDNameKey       |ID     |Name   |Location       |Type   |Active
================|=======|=======|===============|=======|=====
111             |11     |AAA    |LocA           |Type1  |No
222             |22     |BBB    |LocB           |Type2  |Yes
333             |33     |CCC    |LocA           |Type4  |No
444             |11     |AAA    |LocC           |Type2  |Yes
555             |55     |EEE    |LocB           |Type4  |No
666             |22     |BBB    |LocB           |Type2  |Yes
```

Table2 (Expected way)

```
ID      |Name   |Location |Type   |Active Count(Yes)  |Inactive Count(No)
========|=======|=========|=======|===================|=================
11      |AAA    |LocA     |Type1  |1                  |1
22      |BBB    |LocB     |Type2  |2                  |0
33      |CCC    |LocA     |Type4  |0                  |1
55      |EEE    |LocB     |Type4  |0                  |1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional sum

```
    SELECT ID, Name, Location, Type,
          SUM(CASE WHEN Active = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Active Count(Yes)],
          SUM(CASE WHEN Active = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Active Count(No)]

    From (Original SQL command) 
    GROUP BY ID, Name, Location, Type
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, give this a whirl..

```
SELECT ID, Nave, Location, Type, 
   SUM(CASE Active WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 WHEN 'No' THEN 0 END) as [Active Count(Yes)],
   SUM(CASE Active WHEN 'No' THEN 1 WHEN 'Yes' THEN 0 END) as [Inactive Count(No)]
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ID, Nave, Location, Type
```

For a code and image-heavy tutorial on CASE blocks check out my article [SQL Server CASE Solutions](http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/12366/SQL-Server-CASE-Solutions.html)